# Why was the question about the SIPC closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Today, this question was asked:

[Is SIPC a scam or does it protect investors from fraud?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/105244/10997)

It was closed as "unclear what you're asking."

Would one of the users that closed care to comment on what they had trouble understanding about the question?

I understood the question, and was about halfway through composing an answer when it was closed.  I have voted to reopen the question.

Comment: I think it's clear enough given the second paragraph and have reopened, but I think it would benefit from a bit more information from the links in the question being placed inline.

Comment: Questions put on hold are still visible, and I'd suggest that these questions (Ben's meta question) be added as a comment there.  A better question for Meta would be "Can members agree that when voting to close a question as 'unclear', that one or more leave a decent, clear reason why they are voting that way? And further, if the final vote is from a mod, please be sure to do so?"

Comment: Yes, to Ganesh's comment. I read the question twice, and it struck me that as written, it was not answerable. And my timing was bad. I should have made my reason clear, then hit 'close'. Instead, it was 'close', and wife asking me to walk my dog, and the rest of my day took over. (Now that the question is open, @Ben, I'm looking forward to how you'd answer, and also to seeing the issue of link-with-no-summary addressed.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I did leave a comment there as well (which I deleted after posting this meta question), but often leaving my opinion as a comment and voting to reopen results in no action, because it is not very visible.  I believe that discussing individual questions is a valid use of meta. I would love to see reviewers leaving a comment when they vote to close; I nearly always leave a comment when I vote to close.

Comment: Ben - a number of other Mods in the Mod Chat room agree with you on this, using Meta to discuss closed questions. I just wanted to share that w/you. In my opinion, the reason to close, if clarified as a comment on the original question is still preferable. But other mods see the Meta discussions as valuable.